# Unity3D - Unable to run Dedicated Server build

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here are my compile settings:

[image]

Inside docker image build with this recipe:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER armegon

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
RUN echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mono-complete
RUN apt-get install -y net-tools
```

When I run the app I get this error:

```
root@docker-desktop:/home/authorativeclient# ./AuthorativeClient.x86_64 
[UnityMemory] Configuration Parameters - Can be set up in boot.config
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-cache-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-typetree-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-profiler-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-profiler-editor-allocator-block-size=1048576"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-main=4194304"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size-background=1048576"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-reduction-small-platforms=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-background-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-job-worker=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-preload-manager=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-nav-mesh-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-audio-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-cloud-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-gfx=262144"
Mono path[0] = '/home/authorativeclient/AuthorativeClient_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = '/home/authorativeclient/AuthorativeClient_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Found 3 interfaces on host : 0) 192.168.65.3 1) 192.168.65.4 2) 172.17.0.1
Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.65.3 [Port] 55294 [Flags] 19 [Guid] 601533813 [EditorId] 2814462019 [Version] 1048832 [Id] Unknown(43,192.168.65.3) [Debug] 1 [PackageName] Unknown [ProjectName] AuthorativeClient" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
Stopping profiler. Profiler is not able to flush data to a file or socket and exceeded maximum allowed memory for buffering.
Please use Profiler.maxUsedMemory API or -profiler-maxusedmemory command line parameter to increase maximum allowed memory usage.
Using 134234112 bytes while Profiler.maxUsedMemory is 134217728 bytes.
Starting managed debugger on port 56813
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:56813
Preloaded 'lib_burst_generated.so'
Preloaded 'libgrpc_csharp_ext.so'
Unable to load player prefs
Initialize engine version: 2021.3.0f1 (6eacc8284459)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path /home/authorativeclient/AuthorativeClient_Data/UnitySubsystems
Forcing GfxDevice: Null
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=0; jobified=0
NullGfxDevice:
    Version:  NULL 1.0 [1.0]
    Renderer: Null Device
    Vendor:   Unity Technologies
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
* Assertion at tramp-amd64.c:177, condition `(((guint64)(addr)) >> 32) == 0' not met

Caught fatal signal - signo:6 code:-6 errno:0 addr:0x9b
Obtained 48 stack frames.
#0  0x000040048a6520 in __sigaction
#1  0x000040048faa7c in pthread_kill
#2  0x000040048a6476 in raise
#3  0x0000400488c7f3 in abort
#4  0x00004168e60681 in monoeg_assert_abort
#5  0x00004168e49bc2 in mono_dl_fallback_unregister
#6  0x00004168e60999 in monoeg_g_logv
#7  0x00004168e60ad2 in monoeg_assertion_message
#8  0x00004168e60b04 in mono_assertion_message
#9  0x00004168d11253 in mono_breakpoint_clean_code
#10 0x00004168cc06bc in mono_install_ftnptr_eh_callback
#11 0x00004168cbfe14 in mono_install_ftnptr_eh_callback
#12 0x0000418948a396 in (Unknown)
#13 0x00004189edc4e8 in System.RuntimeType:GetConstructorCandidates (string,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.CallingConventions,System.Type[],bool)
#14 0x00004189edc228 in System.RuntimeType:GetConstructors (System.Reflection.BindingFlags)
#15 0x00004189edbb46 in System.RuntimeType:GetDefaultConstructor ()
#16 0x00004189ed774c in System.Text.EncodingHelper:GetDefaultEncoding ()
#17 0x00004189ed7324 in System.Text.Encoding:CreateDefaultEncoding ()
#18 0x00004189ece575 in (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
#19 0x00004168c461e8 in mono_get_runtime_build_info
#20 0x00004168de4dca in mono_runtime_invoke
#21 0x00004168de1465 in mono_runtime_class_init
#22 0x00004168c3ec9f in _init
#23 0x00004168c42548 in mono_jit_set_domain
#24 0x00004168cc03ab in mono_install_ftnptr_eh_callback
#25 0x00004168cbfe14 in mono_install_ftnptr_eh_callback
#26 0x0000418948a396 in (Unknown)
#27 0x00004189ecf92c in UnityEngine.UnityLogWriter:Init ()
#28 0x00004168c461e8 in mono_get_runtime_build_info
#29 0x00004168de4dca in mono_runtime_invoke
#30 0x00004168de4d14 in mono_runtime_invoke
#31 0x000040030cb662 in void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_assign_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)
#32 0x000040030c9237 in void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_assign_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)
#33 0x000040030a6c6f in void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_assign_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)
#34 0x000040030a746d in void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_assign_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)
#35 0x000040030a5102 in void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_assign_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)
#36 0x000040030a5076 in void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_assign_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)
#37 0x00004003135fb7 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, unsigned long, int const&)
#38 0x00004003135845 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, unsigned long, int const&)
#39 0x00004003118a32 in void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_assign_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)
#40 0x00004003119035 in void std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_assign_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)
#41 0x00004002741f23 in operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
#42 0x00004002742052 in operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
#43 0x00004002c5ad25 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_default_append(unsigned long)
#44 0x0000400314d8c5 in PlayerMain(int, char**)
#45 0x0000400488dd90 in __libc_init_first
#46 0x0000400488de40 in __libc_start_main
#47 0x00004000001029 in _start
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
Aborted
```

Any idea why I get this error and how can I solve it?